# How to link Steam and Android accounts?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-legends

How can I link my Google Play account with Steam to preserve progress on mobile, specifically in The Elder Scrolls: Legends?

Answer (score 1):

By using the same [Bethesda account](https://bethesda.net/en/account/manage-account) on both devices.

Comment: I logged in with Google Play account, but still find the option to create Bethesda account in-game. Then when I created Bethesda account with the same email on desktop and log in with that email on mobile, I start over.

Comment: You logged in to ESL using your Google Play account, or you started the game using that account? If you still can/need to log in in-game, I think it's the second one, so it's logical you haven't made any progress there. Your current progress is likely linked to your Google account, so I think you'll have to start over if you want to link the two.

Comment: Or try logging in (or even signing up) using the email address you use for Google Play through Steam.

Comment: I logged in to ESL with Google Play (GP) acc, played for some time. Then I wanted to play on desktop. So I downloaded on computer, and tried to log in with GP. No account found, so I registered on Bethesda with the same email I use for ESL. Data was not synced. 

On android, If I use GP, I have an option on the left bottom side to sign up on Bethesda. If I log out of GP, I can login on my Bethesda account.

Answer (score 0):

I found account linking. When you go to bathesda.net -> login -> your photo -> Linked Accounts. There is Steam option, but no Google Play option.

It is currently not possible to use Google Play account to sync progress between android and desktop.